Find all integral domains $R$ such that $x^{4} = x$ for all $x \in R$.
At the moment, I am not even studying ring theory but I was thinking of the following question.
Question: Find all integral domains $R$ such that $x^{4} = x$ for all $x \in R$.
My initial thought was to rewrite the equation as $x(x - 1)(x^{2} + x + 1) = 0$. From this, solutions $x = 0, x = 1$ and the non-trivial solutions to the equation $x^{3} - 1 = 0$ follow, namely $\omega = e^{2\pi i / 3}$ and $\omega^{2}$. Clearly, the trivial ring $R = \{0\}$ (where $0 = 1$) is one such integral domain. Also, $\mathbb{F}_{2}$ clearly satisfies the condition.
Moreover, I have considered the integral domains $\mathbb{F}_{2}[\omega] = \{a + b\omega \mid a, b \in \mathbb{F}_{2}\}$ and $\mathbb{F}_{2}[\omega^{2}] = \{a + b\omega^{2} \mid a, b \in \mathbb{F}_{2}\}$. These rings also satisfy the condition, since we have for example that $(a + b\omega)^{4} = ((a + b\omega)^{2})^{2} = (a^{2} + b^{2}\omega^{2})^{2} = a^{4} + b^{4}\omega^{4} = a + b\omega$ since $\omega^{3} = 1$.
From this point, I am wondering if I have found all integral domains that satisfy the mentioned condition. I would not be sure on how to proceed in showing that there are any others. If anybody could help that would be greatly appreciated.

The trivial ring is usually not considered an integral domain. Anyway, try to think how many elements such an integral domain might have.

Same idea as here.

$e^x$ doesn't mean anything in an arbitrary ring.

Please do not answer in the comments, @ThomasAndrews.

Let $R$ be an integral domain such that every element of $R$ is a root of $X^4-X\in R[X]$.

As shown in this question the number of roots of a polynomial over an integral domain is at most its degree, and so $|R|\leq4$.
As shown in this question every finite integral domain is a field.
As shown in this question the only fields of such small order are $\Bbb{F}_2$, $\Bbb{F}_3$ and $\Bbb{F}_4$, up to isomorphism.

A quick check shows that only $\Bbb{F}_2$ and $\Bbb{F}_4$ work.


and 2. are not necessary. From $x^n = x$ and $x \neq 0$ we immediately get that $x^{n-1} = 1$.


For the bigger picture you may consult this paper, section 2. Let us call a ring an $n$-ring if $x^n = x$ for all $x$. Then clearly every $n$-domain is an $n$-field (just cancel $x \neq 0$ to get $x^{n-1}=1$), and these are exactly the $\mathbb{F}_q$ with $q-1 \mid n-1$. Table 2 on page 9 in the linked paper mentions some examples. For $n = 4$ the only prime powers are $q = 2,4$. When for example $n = 2023$, we get $q=2,4,3,7$.
